# Download STS old version

Tags: sts, spring-tools-4

I need to download an old STS version.
Specifically I need to download STS 3.9.2.
I had this url saved where I could found all versions:

https://dist.springsource.com/

I tried it today but it doesn't work anymore.

Is there any other repository where I can find that STS version?

Thanks in advance

Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the archived project wiki of the Spring Tool Suite 3, including links to old Spring Tool Suite 3 downloads:

https://github.com/spring-attic/toolsuite-distribution/wiki/Spring-Tool-Suite-3

It does not list your specific version, but you will probably be able to guess the download URL from the ones that are listed on that wiki.

Keep in mind that this old version of the Spring Tool Suite is no longer maintained,